# Spring security authentication-manager has no providers

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, provider

I'm trying to setup a simple project with Spring security to enable Username / pwd login.

After pointing some breakpoint in the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter I noticed that getAuthenticationManager has 0 providers

```
this.getAuthenticationManager()
```

However I did add this in the security-context.xml

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

It looks like the authenticationManager does get rightly autowired but for some reason the authentication-provider is not injected.

Did I forget to enable something somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default SpringSecurity uses `org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager` which initially should have at least one configured provider unless parent is set. Otherwise you will get `IllegalArgumentException` at initialization phase. Therefore you definitely should be able to find an authentication provider either in the authentication manager returned from the filter or in one of its parents (as long as there is no harmful code that removes providers intentionally of course).

Comment: I was looking at the wrong provider. The base provider were empty but there was one in the "parent"

Answer (score 1):

We were facing this issue when upgrading from Spring security 3 to version 4.
We had a `AuthenticationManager` definied as follows

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="rememberMeAuthenticationProvider"/>
    <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

As it turned out using only an `alias` attribute the definied `AuthenticationManager` was not used by Spring.
We needed to define an `id` attribute to make it work.

```
<authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
    ...
</authentication-manager>
```

When no id is specified Spring sets the id to "org.springframework.security.authenticationManager" during the beans parsing in the [`org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerBeanDefinitionParser.parse`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/d31fff11b3bb91e484228f29af469a9a0661dd32/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/authentication/AuthenticationManagerBeanDefinitionParser.java) overriding the globally registered `AuthenticationManager`. This somehow seems to mess up the specified `providers`.